# ProtectedData.Protect Method with CurrentUser in ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, cryptography

In my ASP.NET web application I need to save a password in a database. (Note that this is not a login password and a user providing such password is given a visible security warning.) I was thinking to provide some scrambling for the password before placing it into the database.

So I was thinking to do this:

```
byte[] bytesToSave_Scrambled = 
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password), null,
    System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

The issue is that according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), when I use `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` only that same user account will be able to decode it back. I can of course use `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine` instead, but the documentation says that it is less secure.

So my question is, when my web app runs on a web server, does it run under the same Windows user account to ensure consistency of the scrambling method above?

Comment: That depends on several aspects - for example: is the web server part of a AD-Domain ? How is the web server configured regarding authentication ? etc.

Comment: @Yahia: Hmm. I don't know that upfront. So I guess `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine` is the way to go, hah?

Comment: If you don't know that upfront then: yes, either use `LocalMachine` or a configurable key (which is better in case they need to move the application to another machine) together with a known secure algorithm...